# problem when clicking a button to fetch weather data from outside API

Tags: javascript, api, request

I have a weather app where i fetch data from outside API.. i have an input where i type a city name and get the weather info when clicking on search icon..the problem is, i have to refresh the page many times to get the data even after i type the city name and click the button.. i need to get the data once i type the city name and click the button..what is wrong with my code??..
i have 2 files linked in HTML page
the first contain the request function
[image: request code]

the second one is the app.js file where i call the function from the first file
[image: function call]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `weather(inputValue, (error, weatherData)=>{});` inside the click event listener
like this:

```
search.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

weather(inputValue, (error, weatherData)=>{

//Do the rest here

});

});
```